# Convergence in probability of (1+1/n)X to X

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Consider $X$ with an arbitrary probability distribution. Is it true that $$X_n = (1+\frac{1}{n})X$$ converges in probability to $X$ regardless of the distribution?

Here is my proof (maybe there is something wrong)

We know by definition that convergence in probability means

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon) = 0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(|(1+\frac{1}{n})X-X| \geq \epsilon) = 0$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(|X+\frac{1}{n}X-X| \geq \epsilon) = 0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(|\frac{1}{n}X| \geq \epsilon) = 0$$

we can now apply Chebyshev's inequality to the left hand side

$$P(|\frac{1}{n}X| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{n^2\epsilon^2}$$

So as long as $Var(X) \leq \infty$. Is something wrong here?

Comment: As long as $Var(X) < \infty$ that's allright.

Comment: Isn't that weird though?

Comment: Why should that be weird? $X_n$ converges even pointwise.

Comment: Well, I have no good response, the reason I think it is weird is because I was expecting an exponential(1) distribution since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})=e$ but I'm just looking for patterns where there are none

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n}) = 0$. I assume, what you are thinking about is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$

Comment: You don't need the existence of variance or even of expectation of $X$, and your original statement didn't require them.  There is a better argument than the Chebyshev one.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But his way needs it. That's why i said it even converges pointwise.

Comment: Btw, there is a little typo above, it has to be $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n}) = 1$